# Problems with mainThread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, wait, jtextpane

im trying to solve that problem for days. My program editing images.
im not using multithreading.

i am using a function (private void console()) that writes formatted text in a JTextPane.
i have a class called ImageWork() that works with my pictures.

my problem: i call first the `console("start with work")` function, after that i call a 
function of my class to editing an image (it takes some time). then i called another time my console("finish") function. i have tried many things that the method to editing the image wait till the console function is ready without success :(.
so every time i call the 3 functions first the image will be edited, then the console function writes in my textpane both texts.

```
private void color2gray()             
{           
       console("start")       
    try         
       {  
        myImg.color2gray();   
        console("success");   
        repaint();    
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        console("no success");
    }
```

the program works fine. my problem is that i want that text in my console (JtextPane) that the function starts now and then the function color2gray starts because that function could take one minute with big pictures.

i have already tried things like change console return type to boolean and call that:

```
  while (!(console("start")) {};
```

I would be pleased if there finds someone an solution for that problem. Thanks

console() code:

```
private void console(String str,boolean fehler)         
{               
    time=new GregorianCalendar();

    String help=time.getTime().toString();
    help=help.substring(0,19);

    doc = (StyledDocument) console.getDocument();
    Style style = doc.addStyle("StyleName", null);

    StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.black);
    try { doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),help, style); } 
    catch (BadLocationException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    if (fehler) StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.red);
    else StyleConstants.setForeground(style, new Color(0,125,0));

    try {   doc.insertString(doc.getLength()," :  "+str+"\n", style); } 
    catch (BadLocationException e1) { e1.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you problem is.  Please edit your post to make it more clear.

Comment: We need to see more code.

Comment: ok wait i try to make that clear

Comment: What happens? Do you get exceptions or does the program never exit?

Comment: Don't know how relevant this is, but you start by saying you're not using multithreading - but the Swing framework is multithreaded... see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: yes i know that but i am not opening any threads by myself

Comment: no exception it works fine but i called the console("start") first so my programm should run this function first, but first the editing method myImg.color2gray starts and then if that is finished both texts appear at the same time "start" and "success"

Comment: selig gave you the answer. Read the tutorial. You should use a SwingWorker.

Comment: ok i will read that tutorial and maybe find my answer in that but is there no simple method to say my programm to wait for this small console method to finish  i have never worked with that swings to create an gui

Comment: It is a simple method. Your long running task needs to execute in a separate Thread so you don't prevent the GUI from repainting itself. The SwingWorker creates this Thread for you and allows you to "publish" results as they become available so you can update the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the name of the thread that invokes color2gray()?   Add this to the first line of that function to find out:

```
System.out.println("Thread = " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

You may see an output like this:

Thread = AWT-EventQueue-0

Which means the code is running on the "event thread".  This should be the only thread that modifies Swing/GUI components.  AND this thread should NOT do long-running work.  If this is the event thread, then you need to do your long work in the background.

change

```
myImg.color2gray();
```

to

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      myImg.color2gray();
  }
};
t.start();
```

As a start.  And read more about the swing event thread:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread

Comment: thanks for the fast answers. i solve that problem with a SwingWorker but i also tried to make it like Keith, but there are more functions so i could work with this swingWorker again.